# Google style autocomplete & autocorrection with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to achieve google style autocomplete & autocorrection with elasticsearch.

Mappings :

```
POST music
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "nGram_filter": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 20,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "punctuation",
            "symbol"
          ]
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "nGram_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding",
            "nGram_filter"
          ]
        },
        "whitespace_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "song": {
      "properties": {
        "song_field": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
        },
        "suggest": {
          "type": "completion",
          "analyzer": "simple",
          "search_analyzer": "simple",
          "payloads": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Docs:

```
POST music/song
{
  "song_field" : "beautiful queen",
  "suggest" : "beautiful queen"
}

POST music/song
{
  "song_field" : "beautiful",
  "suggest" : "beautiful"
}
```

I expect that when user types: "`beaatiful q`" he will get something like `beautiful queen` (beaatiful is corrected to beautiful and q is completed to queen).

I've tried the following query:

```
POST music/song/_search?search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch
{
  "size": 10,
  "suggest": {
    "didYouMean": {
      "text": "beaatiful q",
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "song_field": {
        "query": "beaatiful q",
         "fuzziness": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, [Completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html) doesn't allow any typos so I get this response:

```
"suggest": {
    "didYouMean": [
      {
        "text": "beaatiful q",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 11,
        "options": []
      }
    ]
  }
```

In addition, search gave me these results (beautiful ranked higher although user started to wrote "queen"):

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "music",
        "_type": "song",
        "_id": "AVUj4Y5NancUpEdFLeLo",
        "_score": 0.51315063,
        "_source": {
          "song_field": "beautiful"
          "suggest": "beautiful"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "music",
        "_type": "song",
        "_id": "AVUj4XFAancUpEdFLeLn",
        "_score": 0.32071912,
        "_source": {
          "song_field": "beautiful queen"
          "suggest": "beautiful queen"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**UPDATE !!!**

I found out that I can use fuzzy query with completion suggester, but now I get no suggestions when querying (fuzzy only supports 2 edit distance):

```
POST music/song/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "suggest": {
    "didYouMean": {
      "text": "beaatefal q",
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest",
        "fuzzy" : {
                "fuzziness" : 2
            }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I still expect "`beautiful queen`" as suggestion response.

Comment: In the search part, you should use `match_phrase` if you want to match on several words. However, if the user types `beaatiful q` I don't get how you can have `beautiful q` in the search part...

Comment: @Val when user sends 'beaatiful q' I expect to get back 'beautiful queen' as suggestion.

Comment: I was just commenting about the search part, not the suggestion part. My question was how come if the user enters `beaatiful q` you can have `beaatiful q` in the suggestion part and `beautiful q`  in the search part?

Comment: @Val that's a typo. I've edited the ques.

Comment: Have you tried `match_phrase` instead of `match`?

Comment: @Val the closest I got is sending this query:
"suggest": {
    "text": "beuateful q",
    "didYouMean": {
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest",
        "fuzzy" : {
                "fuzziness" : 2
            }
      }
    }
  }

Comment: @Val when sending:
"query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "song_field": {
        "query": "beaatiful q",
         "fuzziness": 2
      }
    }
  }

I get 0 hits

Comment: Of course, because there's a typo in it. My comment about `match_phrase` was when you had `beautiful q` in your search query.

Comment: @Val my goal is to get a reasonable results back even when the user have typos. Just like google search engine.
For "beeuateful q" I expect to get "beautiful  queen".
Fuzzy search limits to 2 edit distance.

Comment: @ohadinho, you may want to try the ES Shingles analyzer coupled with a match_phrase_prefix query.  I've been working on an autocomplete feature using ES and that works pretty well if you want Google like functionality. Shingles analyzer is also cheaper than ngrams.

Comment: @user3125823 can you provide an exapmle ?

Comment: @ohadinho just submitted an answer with some info on Shingles, its rough but should get you started - when I have more time, Ill edit the answer and be more complete

Comment: @user3125823 still the best results I got is using the following query:

"suggest": { "text": "beuateful q", "didYouMean": { "completion": { "field": "suggest", "fuzzy" : { "fuzziness" : 2 } } } }

Comment: @ohadinho, do what works! I learned a lot depends on your data and your chosen tokenizers and token filters. I tried the completion suggester myself but I like using the Shingles more. Its a learning process, code, test and repeat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to provide 2 or more words as search suggestions, I have found out (the hard way), its not worth it to use ngrams or edgengrams in Elasticsearch.

Using the [Shingles token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) and the [shingles analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/blog/searching-with-shingles) will provide you with multi-word phrases and if you couple that with the match_phrase_prefix it should give you the functionality your looking for.

Basically something like this:

```
    PUT /my_index
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,  
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "my_shingle_filter": {
                    "type":             "shingle",
                    "min_shingle_size": 2, 
                    "max_shingle_size": 2, 
                    "output_unigrams":  false   
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "my_shingle_analyzer": {
                    "type":             "custom",
                    "tokenizer":        "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "my_shingle_filter" 
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And don't forget to do your mapping:

```
{
"my_type": {
    "properties": {
        "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
                "shingles": {
                    "type":     "string",
                    "analyzer": "my_shingle_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Ngrams and edgengrams are going tokenize single characters, whereas the Shingles analyzer and filters, groups letters (making words) and provide a much more efficient way of producing and searching for phrases. I spent alot of time messing with the 2 above until I saw Shingles mentioned and read up on it. Much better.

Comment: does not give expected result